# Changing ajax to request that fills a div with html content to be embedded into the html page itself

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, seo, infrastructure

I am having a trouble embedding ajax html into the html page itself, I need to make this ajax response be apparent in the page source.

I have 2 servers, one that runs the web application and the other is responsible for performing search queries (searcher). Now the application server sends the html page to the client's browser, which will request some search queries to searcher through ajax, after the successful reply the browser will put the html result into the page.

The problem is that search results do not exist in the html source which is not good for SEO, google crawlers will have no idea what is being searched for.

The other problem is if I made the application server make a request and wait for searcher results, the page will take tons of seconds to load.

I am not sure what to do.. I really need to make the website SEO friendly and also need the page to load quickly!!

Any pointers or ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Wa'el

Comment: I am not sure what would be the best solution here but do not consider serving different results for the two cases - i.e. application server requesting and waiting for results in crawlers case and ajax case normally. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916147/how-to-identify-web-crawlers-of-google-yahoo-msn-by-php/916222#916222

Comment: @Sandeepan, thanks for your reply, serving different results will cause the page to take a long time to be executed in application server. The link might be a solution, does lot of websites do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to get Ajax provided data to be present in the "source" in this case as the source is always the original page requested from the server before any client side changes.

And any kind of client that does NOT support javascipt, like search engine crawlers, will never se any ajax loaded data.

If you need the information to be indexable you need to 
1: serve the page as in from the server, no client side loading
2: Not use posted forms fo reach the data, search engines do not folow posts, only get links.

Comment: The ajax response is the related items for the contribution that is being viewed, of course each item has different related items. With limited resources I need to get the related items fast from the application server... It wont be database queries.. should I use caching (eg memcached, redis)?? I am not sure it will make any benifit... How big websites like youtube are doing this?!

Comment: In that case, use standard links that link to the new information but that are transformed info ajax calls on load if the client supports javascript. And have the landingpage that the original links go to be the same page as the list but with arguments to make it load the refered item directly on load.