# Set Cookie on Age Gate only for Real Visitors

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, cookies, opencart

I'm building an adult toy store in OpenCart and the wholesale company requires an age gate, which I've built using a simple cookie script in the header file:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['agecheck'])):
    $this->redirect ($this->url->link('common/agegate'));
endif;
```

This works great when the visitor is a live person, but when trying to use social sharing buttons the cookie is blocking Facebook, Google+, LinkedIn from accessing the correct product page.

Does anyone know of a solution for this? A solution using jQuery would also be acceptable.

Comment: So You are simply asking how can Facebook, Google+ and LinkedIn access Your adult toys' shop and for example create a post with some juicy product image and thrilling product description with hot link to Your site? Anyway there are some checks how to distinguish that the *visitor* is a bot/spider/crawler (e.g. Google's Indexing bot) and that You want to let him in without age check - just google for *PHP how to distinguish spider against real user* (or follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916147/how-to-identify-web-crawlers-of-google-yahoo-msn-by-php))...

Comment: I resolved it with jQuery.cookie plugin. Went from a header() redirect to using a nice modal which is ignored by the listed referrers. Thanks for your help though.